# remove character "\" from json string

Tags: java

I need to remove "\" character from json string after executing GET command in java

I tried to remove by replace method but unable to remove

response = ["{
  \"isEnriched\":\"true\",\"event\":{\"commonEventHeader\":{\"startEpochMicrosec\":\"1555099630557000\"}}}"]
responseBody = response.replaceAll("\", " ");

Unable to replace "\" with blank space

Comment: When using `'\'` in strings, you need to escape it: `'\\'`. And since [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) uses regex, you need to escape it again: `'\\\\'`. Though, you might be better off using a real json parser. [How to parse JSON in Java](//stackoverflow.com/q/2591098)

Comment: Can you post an actual snippet of Java code? Your example doesn't seem to compile.

Comment: Also note there are actually no backslashes in the text you have provided. Those `\"` are escaped double quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work:

```
 "{\"isEnriched\":\"true\",\"event\":{\"commonEventHeader\":{\"startEpochMicrosec\":\"1555099630557000\"}}}".replace("\\", "");
```

you need to use "\\" because \ is an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `response.replaceAll("\\\\", "")`.

In Java `\` is escape character. Thus to escape it you need one `\` and to make it a '\' you need 2 `\` to escape each `\`

Comment: Thank you all , this worked .